# Django IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, django

Учу Django по [Writing your first Django app (ver. 1.5)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

- ОС: Windows 7
- IDE: SublimeText2 и PyCharm

Следуя туториалу, я создал проект `newweb` в `C:\DjangoProjects`.
И потом в `newweb`  создал приложение `polls`.
Вот такая структура каталогов у меня имеется:

```
newweb/
    manage.py
    newweb/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
```

В файле `models.py` у меня следующий код (из туториала):

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Когда я выполняю этот код в Sublime Text 2 (и в PyCharm то же самое), получаю такую ошибку:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DjangoProjects\newweb\polls\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Poll(models.Model):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 93, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Смысл этой фигни в том, что Джанго обрабатывая `model`, парсит имя приложения модели. И обращается, к предпоследнему индексу, как к имени приложения. Здесь это почему то не работает у меня (и Джанго не может определить родительское приложение). Я так это понимаю.

Я читал, что чтобы пофиксить это, надо добавить meta class к каждому классу в `models.py` (и это работает).

**НО(!)** в офф. документации Джанго написано следующее:

> If a model exists outside of the
>   standard locations (models.py or a
>   models package in an app), the model
>   must define which app it is part of.

И это не мой случай.

Так что с этим не то? Все должно хорошо работать и **без** meta классов.

#### Конфигурация

- Приложение `polls` включено в  `INSTALLED_APPS` в `settings.py`.
- Я синхронизировал базу данных (sqlite3), используя `manage.py syncdb`

И вот что у меня в `PYTHONPATH`:

```
[' ', 
'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\DjangoProjects\\newweb', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\python27\\lib', 
'C:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\python27', 
'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Если требуется знать еще что-то — только скажите.

Comment: А как само приложение запускаете при ошибке? python manage.py runserver ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте поменять структуру проекта на такую

   ```
   newweb/
       polls/
           __init__.py
           admin.py
           models.py
           tests.py
       __init__.py
       manage.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
   ```

   и в **INSTALLED_APPS** в **settings.py** поменяйте строку **polls** на   **newweb.polls**
   По крайне мере я с такой структурой создавал проекты в django 1.4
2. Без class meta у вас django ищет в БД таблицу newweb_Poll, поэтому если у вас таблица в БД называется Poll, то неплохо бы написать такое

   ```
   class Poll(models.Model):
       question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

       class Meta:
           db_table = u'Poll'
   ```